# Object Array Initialization

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am reposting my question.

There are 3 reference variables root1,root2,root3,they are included in a reference array (root[]={root1,root2,root3}).

I initialized the object for root[0],I hope root[0] refers to root1 ,So i expect root1.data and root[0].data to access the same value.But i am not able to access using root1.data whereas i am able to access it using root[0].data.

```
public class testing 
{
static Node root1,root2,root3;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Node root[]={root1,root2,root3};
        root[0]=new Node(2,null);
        System.out.println("root[0]="+root[0].data);//It is working properly
        System.out.println("root1="+root1.data);//It is not working properly
    }
    public static class Node
    {
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int data,Node next)
        {
            this.next=next;
            this.data=data;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need all your nodes be static? try to do it without the static-modifier but the main method

Comment: Why do you repost your question? Edit your original question instead. I vote to close this question as duplicate of the original question.

Comment: Please be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables and array elements are all *references* to objects. They are not the actual objects.

To illustrate, I'll "name" actual objects using a number scheme, e.g. #1 is the first object.

Your code runs as follows:

- Class is initialized by the JVM, and `root1`, `root2`, and `root3` are all **`null`**.
- `Node root[]={root1,root2,root3}` is executed and it creates a `Node[]` object (#1) with length of 3, and *copies* the **`null`** values of `root1`, `root2`, and `root3`. The code is equivalent to:

  ```
  Node[] root = new Node[3];
  root[0] = root1;
  root[1] = root2;
  root[2] = root3;
  ```
- `root[0]=new Node(null,2)` is executed and creates a `Node` object (#2) and assigns it to `root[0]`. Note that `root1` remains **`null`**.
- `root1=new Node(null,3)` is executed and creates a `Node` object (#3) and assigns it to `root1`. Note that `root[0]` still references #2.
- You print the value of `root[0].data`, and since `root[0]` references #2, it will print `2`.
- You print the value of `root1.data`, and since `root1` references #3, it will print `3`.

Everything works the way it should.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not supposed to access the same value,

After initializing your array, you simple put in each node a null value

```
     root[0]=new Node(null,2);
```

The new created node will be referenced by the first node in the array , array1 still has value of null

```
         root1=new Node(null,3);
```

now root1 one is pointing to the new node

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the simplified code that has the same behavior:

```
public class Testing2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node r1 = new Node(1);
        Node r2 = r1;
        r1 = new Node(2);

        System.out.println("r1=" + r1.data);// prints 2
        System.out.println("r2=" + r2.data);// prints 1
    }

    public static class Node {
        int data;

        Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

It is important to understand that r1 and r2 are **pointing** at  Node objects. In some languages r1 and r2 would be called pointers, in Java they are called references.

When you execute:

```
Node r1 = new Node(1);
```

You have r1 pointing at the instance of Node with data = 1

```
r1 -> Node.data=1
```

After

```
Node r2 = r1;
```

You have both r1 and r2 pointing at the same Node instance

```
r1 -> Node.data=1 <- r2
```

Finally after

```
r1 = new Node(2);
```

You have

```
        Node.data=1  <- r2
r1 ->   Node.data=2
```

Which explains the output of the program.